# Aligning text on bottom of the QTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, text-alignment, qtextedit

I have a `QWidget` called `side` and `QTextEdit` inside it's `sideLayout` layout.

```
chatView = QTextEdit()
chatView.setHtml('<p style="margin: 0px; line-height: 28px;">')
sideLayout.addWidget(tab.chatView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Below the `QTextEdit` there's a `QLineEdit` called `inputLine`, where I write text and send it to `QTextEdit` via `.append(inputLine.text())` on `Return`.

I want each new line (the `<p>` element) to appear on the bottom, and each new line being appended below first one.

This is how it looks now:

[image: Text not aligned to bottom]

I tried `setStylesheet()` with `p { vertical-align: bottom; }`.
I tried `p { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; }`
I tried `setAlignment()` with `Qt.AlignBottom`.

How can I make lines align to the bottom like this?

[image: Desired alignment]

Answer (score 5):

If the chat-view is going to be read-only, you don't really need a text-edit. Just use a `QLabel`, and then `setAligment` will work as expected:

```
self.chatView = QtGui.QLabel(self)
self.chatView..setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
```

To append text, you can do something like:

```
self.chatView.setText(
    '%s<p>%s</p>'
    % (self.chatView.text(), self.inputLine.text()))
```

(PS: you may also need to put the label in a `QScrollArea`).

Comment: Oh, true, I didn't think of that. I will try it tomorrow and report back. I knew `QLabel` supports rich text and html.